# Solve command fails when applied to this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following equation (exp1=1) which i would like to solve for w:

```
C1 = (3 + w^2 - 3 w Coth[w])/w^4;
C2 = (18 + 6 Cosh[2 w]-23 w Coth[w]-w Cosh[3 w] Csch[w])/(4 w^4);
C3 = Csch[w] (4 w + 2 w Cosh[2 w] - 3 Sinh[2 w])/w^4;
exp1 = w^2 (C1 + 2 Exp[w] (C3 + 2 C2 Exp[w] + C3 Exp[2 w])/(Exp[2 w] - 1)^2);
```

When I try solving using

```
NSolve[exp1 == 1, {w, Reals}]
```

I get no solution. Same thing happens  with Find Root.

The solution to the equation is `w = 1.6169216675118865`.
How can this value be obtained using Mathematica?
Any help will be most appreciated.
Thanks in advance
r k

Comment: `Simplify[exp1 == 1]` gives `True`!

Comment: `Simplify[exp1 // TrigToExp] ` gives `1`

Comment: Simplify[exp1]  gives 1!

Comment: Also, `Factor[exp1 // TrigToExp]` and `Refine[exp1 // TrigExpand]` both give `1`.

Comment: Hi RK, based on your values of C1, C2, C3 and exp1, exp1 equal one for all values of w. Just for fun if I ignore the values you provide for C1, C2, C3 and do `Solve[exp1 == 1 /. w -> 1.6169216675118865]` I get `C3 -> 0.855277 - 2.23607 C1 - 0.381966 C2`

Comment: tqvm for all your inputs!